# How to map a folder to memory?

Tags: windows, memory, cache, hard-drive, directory

Is there a way to map a particular folder to memory? Say I have C:\somePath and I want that folder to be in memory at all times and maybe changes are dumped to HDD asynchronously without my notice. So this is more like a forced caching of HDD content in memory... For Windows 7 or any windows OS?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: To have faster read write times.

Comment: I second this - is there something like tmpfs?

Answer (score 2):

You need 3rd party software to do this. One program that can do this is [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk). ImDisk will create a new drive letter which you can make a link to from any folder you want: `mklink /D C:\somePath E:\somePath`.

Answer (score 0):

by default the windows cache manager does an OK job of managing cache size and will not add too much cache to a system.  You can tweak the cache size but not the contents by default.

Comment: So this approach is not possible in Windows?